# Calculate the matrix M(T) representing T relative to input basis E and output basis E'

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let$\  T:P_2(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R^2 $
be the transformation
$\ T(p(x))=(p′(−1),p′′(0))$

$\ E=\{1, x, x^2\}$ the standard basis of $P_2(\mathbb R)$
$\ E′={(1,0), (0,1)}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$

I have to write matrix $M(T)$ with $T$ relative to input basis $E$ and output basis $E'$.
I have been trying different things for hours but couldn't solve it. Any help is appreciated.

I tried doing
$\ p(1) \,\leadsto\, (1', 1'') = (0, 0)$
$\ p(x) \,\leadsto\, (x', x'') = (1, 0)$
$\ p(x^2) \,\leadsto ((x^2)', (x^2)'')= (-2,2)$

so the matrix is

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
That's what I tried to do but it is wrong. I can do the same type of question for different linear transformations and different bases but for some reason I'm stuck at this.

Comment: It looks right to me. The columns of the matrix should be the images of the basis vectors (first column is image of 1, second column is image of $x$, third is image of $x^2$).

Comment: @Nick For some reason my webwork doesn't accept it as correct. Maybe there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to do it abstractly first. Let $e_1,e_2,e_2$ be the basis for the domain, and $f_1,f_2$ the basis for the codomain. Then the matrix entries for $T$ are given by
$$
Te_j=T_{1j}f_1+T_{2j}f_2.
$$
So here
$$
T(1)=(0,0),\qquad T(x)=(1,0)=f_1,\qquad T(x^2)=(-2,2)=-2\,f1+2f_2.
$$
So the matrix you found is right,
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&-2\\ 0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: For some reason my webwork doesn't accept it as correct. Maybe there is something wrong with it.